# Are sudden adiabatic expansions reversible or irreversible? (Tyre burst problems)

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Encountered Question:

> The tube of the tyre of a car is filled with air at $\pu{27^\circ C}$ and  $\pu{2 atm}$ pressure. If the tube suddenly bursts, the final temperature of the air will be ($γ_\textrm{air}=1.5$) ____.

Approach [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/air-is-filled-in-a-tube-of-the-wheel-of-a-car-at-27circ/):

Given:
$T_1 = \pu{27 K}+ \pu{273K}=\pu{300K}$ ,$P_ 1 = \pu{2atm}$

in the process

$T_1^γP_1^{γ−1} = T_2^γ​P_2^{γ−1}$

gives

$T_2 = (2^{-1/3}) \pu{300 K}= \pu{240 K}$

> Q: The pressure inside a tyre is 4atm at 27C. If the tyre bursts suddenly, the new temperature will be $(\gamma = \frac75)$_____.
>
> Ans: $300(4)^{-2/7}$
>
> [Source](http://www.venkatsacademy.com/2017/01/thermodynamics-problems-with-solutions-three.html)

The above approach is correct if we assume reversible process but as bursting is very fast we should assume it is an irreversible process, hence $\Delta U = W_\textrm{on system}$ gives

$\frac{f}{2}nR(T_2-T_1) = -P_{ext}(V_2-V_1)$

Putting values gives $T=\pu{250 K}$.

*So, why do we assume tyre bursting is a reversible process OR are above sources incorrect?*

Comment: Yes you are right, bursting of tire should be considered irreversible.

Comment: Yes, the sources aren't correct. The first source is actually quite faulty and unreliable and in the second source it seems by seeing the webpage that the source is a website of physics (targeting IITJEE), also, in physics that is asked in IITJEE, every thermodynamic process is taken to be reversible one , that is why they assumed the process to be reversible adiabatic . But as @NisargBhavsar pointed out, the process should be irreversible adiabatic.

Comment: Thanks I will add answer soon and feel free to answer if you have better possible answer.

Comment: The adjective *sudden* does not fit well the noun *equilibrium*, which is a required state along paths of reversible processes. By other words, reversible system processes are those, where a closed cycle of system states can by achieved by the closed cycle of the environment state, so the closed path $\Delta S_tot=0$. ( Not to be confused with other meaning of reversibility as 2 way process.). In the first sense it is the opposite to what @ecneics said: Truly reversible process does not exist, as intermediate process states are not in true equilibrium, unless the process takes infinite time.

Comment: The second approach actually assumes that the expansion is irreversible, against the constant pressure of the surrounding atmosphere, and gets the right answer.

Comment: Dear Jay, please write the question in text here because it may happen in the future that the site linked get deleted.

Comment: Pl see this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71529/can-we-have-some-tools-to-handle-link-rot) @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion from comments:

1. Sources are incorrect.
2. Second approach is correct assuming expansion is irreversible against the constant pressure of the surrounding atmosphere and hence gets the right answer.